# error HE0003: Could not load the framework 'CoreSimulator' :not found

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, emulation

I want to develop crossed based apps and chose the xamarin platform, but when I start my visual studio and try to run the hello world application, only the android emulator is running well. If I try the iOS emulator, it gives me this error

> error HE0003: Could not load the framework 'CoreSimulator' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/CoreSimulator):
>   not found.

I am working on a MacBook and my XCode is up-to-date, so I really don't know the problem

I also ran a XCode hello world project and there the emulator reacts well.

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58417

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue while running project in Xamarin studio. Have you resolved this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a couple hours but I got mine working after being in this state.  It was a two step process.

First, I updated Visual Studio for Mac to all the latest versions.

Then, per [this thread](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60156), I used VS4M to create a new Xamarin Forms project and run it.